# Using a backwards relation (i.e FOO_set) for ModelChoiceField in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Movie, which has a ManyToManyField called director to a model called Person, and I'm trying to create a form with ModelChoiceField like so:

```
class MovieSearchForm(forms.Form):
    producer = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Produced by',
                                      queryset=movies.models.Person.producer_set,
                                      required=False)
```

but this seems to be failing to compile (I'm getting a ViewDoesNotExist exception for the view that uses the form, but it goes away if I just replace the queryset with all the person objects), I'm guessing because '.producer_set' is being evaluated too 'early'. How can I get this work?

here are the relevant parts of the movie/person classes:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="producers")
    director = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="directors")
```

What I'm trying to do is get ever Person who is used in the producer field of some Movie.

Comment: Can you give your model classes written as code (at least relevant parts). You are describing you have m2m for director, but you are trying to get producers? Also giving the actual error message with part of stack trace is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a comment asking for more detailed description, but here are some pointers to get you on the right track:

1) You should add `.all()` in the end of the statement.

2) You should add use `objects` or some other manager in the statement between Model and field.

3) You are querying producer_set of a person. Logically I would assume that you should be querying Movie model for producers like this (depending on your model and usecase): `queryset=movies.models.Movie.objects.producers.all()`.